# How to set maximum number of logfiles (Sharepoint 2010)?

Tags: logging, server-farm, settings

How can I prevent my sharepoint server from generating mass amounts of logfiles? In the central adminstration I can only configure the maximum size per file + the time to keep them.

With the managment console I'm also not able to see a setting like "MaxNumberOfLogfiles" or something like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Log files are generates every 30 minutes by default. So you can manage count of files by changing time to keep files and new file creation duration.

[MSDN: You can change the interval by using Windows PowerShell with the Set-SPDiagosticConfig command. The following code snippet configures SharePoint to create a new trace log every 60 minutes.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg193966.aspx)

```
Set-SPDiagnosticConfig -LogCutInterval 60
```

Answer (score 1):

You have several options.

1. You can set the max size in GB that the log files can occupy.
2. Move the log file location other than default which allows more space
3. Make sure the event throttling is configured properly. I would suggest using default throttling levels and setting to “information” or “verbose” only for selected categories and only when it is needed.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the frequency of the logging. For example below Powershell command sets logging interval to 3 hours

```
Set-SPDiagnosticConfig Set-SPDiagnosticConfig -LogCutInterval 180
```

Also, you can fine tune the trace and event log levels from Event throttling section in Central administration.

For details, Check this out : http://extreme-sharepoint.com/2012/05/25/troubleshooting-sharepoint-2010-tools-techniques/